# Here map lon/lat query over dateline

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, here-api

I have some trouble at a location query with here maps. 
I have stored many points in my database with longitude and latitude. 
I request a rectange with HERE api and got the coordinates from the northwest and southeast corner.

for example:

```
Lon: -19°/ Lat: 55° // Lon: 49°/ Lat:36°
```

This works well:

But if i request i rectangele near Australia i reach the dateline and i will got a positive and negative latitude.

for example:

```
Lon: 113° / Lat: -12° // Lon: -177° /Lat: -36°
```

How can i request points if rectangle is over the dateline (113° --> -177° ) 
Does anybody have some MYSQL query.

Comment: Interesting question, never thought about that border case.

Comment: I think the standard formulas address this!!

Comment: Do you need help creating the rectangle or bringing the points inside that rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

The API need Upper Left Corner and Bottom Right Corner.

***HERE*** [example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/geoshapes/rectangle-on-the-map)

So

```
function addRectangleToMap(map) {
  var boundingBox = new H.geo.Rect(53.1, 170.1, 43.1, -170.1);
  map.addObject(
    new H.map.Rect(boundingBox, {
      style: {
        fillColor: '#FFFFCC',
        strokeColor: '#E8FA75',
        lineWidth: 8
      },
    })
  );
}
```

[image]